# Could UV lasers be used to split CO2 and H2O?

Tags: physical-chemistry, synthesis, photochemistry, fuel

I was wondering whether intense UV light, tuned to the correct wavelength, could be used to split carbon dioxide and water molecules as a first step towards synthesizing liquid fuels.

Comment: Sure, though it might not be the most efficient way of doing things.